# How do I mod_rewrite my URL to show only subfolders in URL?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, webserver

I have the following URLs:

```
www.domain.com/subfolder/item.php?test=1
www.domain.com/subfolder/item2.php
```

I want to rewrite the URLs to show only the subfolder:

```
www.domain.com/subfolder/
```

This is what i have so far (in document root?):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^.]+)/$ /$1/$2.php?rw=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^rw=1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^.]+)\.php$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Result:

```
www.domain.com/subfolder/item/
www.domain.com/subfolder/item2/
```

Is there a "generic rule" producing a URL only showing the subfolders regardless of whether there are GET-parameters or not. I have a lot of pages and don´t want to handle every existing case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What url are you entering in your browser for the example 1? your pattern is matching a url in this format=> example.com/foo/bar/

Comment: You are absolutely right. I didn´t realize that example 1 is working also with this rule. Do you have an idea how to hide the subfolder in my/your example so URL is showing example.com/foo/ instead of example.com/foo/bar/.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/item.php?test=$1 [L] 

this will map example.com/20 **to** example.com/subfolder/item.php?test=20

Comment: I don't understand why you are using QUERY_STRING.. what do you want to achive with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder.*$ /subfolder/?  [R=301,L]
```

Input:

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/item.php?test=1
```

Resulting URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/
```

The rule will re-write all URLs with `http://www.domain.com/subfolder/*` with `http://www.domain.com/subfolder/`, and `?` at the end of `/subfolder/?` will omit the query string.

As for options, you can choose whatever is best for you.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev. I think i misunderstood the RewriteRule. I just want to change the URL name, not redirecting to this directory. Can you help me again?